# Can not acces backend in graphql spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, graphql

Im working on a simple coding challenge that needs to createe a graphql application and save some objects (team,players,competitions and coach).
I´ve never used graphql before so iim relying on sove tutorials on the web like: https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-graphql-mysql-jpa/ and https://medium.com/@memredemir/creating-a-graphql-mysql-and-spring-boot-backend-service-32cec95f4436.

For some reason i cant acces the backend for debug:
[image: Sreenshot of postman]

This is my schema wiith the mutations and the types:

```
# leagueSchema.graphqls

# Types

type Team {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    tla: String
    shortName: String
    areaName: String
    address: String
    players: [Player!]
    coach: Coach
    competitions: [Competition!]
}

type Player {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    position: String!
    dateOfBirth: String! # Utilizando String para representar LocalDate em GraphQL
    nationality: String
    team: Team
}

type Coach {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    dateOfBirth: String!  # Representando LocalDate como String
    nationality: String
    team: Team
}

type Competition {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    code: String
    areaName: String
    teams: [Team!]
}

# Queries
type Query {
    getAllTeams: [Team]
    getTeamById(id: ID!): Team
    getAllPlayers: [Player]
    getPlayerById(id: ID!): Player
    getAllCoaches: [Coach]
    getCoachById(id: ID!): Coach
    getAllCompetitions: [Competition]
    getCompetitionById(id: ID!): Competition
}

# Mutations
type Mutation {
    createTeam(name: String!, address: String, areaName: String, shortName: String, tla: String): Team
    createPlayer(name: String!, position: String!, dateOfBirth: String!, nationality: String, teamId: ID!): Player
    createCoach(name: String!, dateOfBirth: String!, nationality: String, teamId: ID!): Coach
    createCompetition(name: String!): Competition
    addTeamToCompetition(teamId: ID!, competitionId: ID!): Competition
    addPlayerToTeam(playerId: ID!, teamId: ID!): Team
    addCoachToTeam(coachId: ID!, teamId: ID!): Team
}
```

And this is my mutation class:

```
@Component
public class TeamMutationResolver implements GraphQLMutationResolver {

    @Autowired
    private TeamService teamService;

    public Team createTeam(@Nonnull String name, String address, String areaName, String shortName, String tla) {
        return teamService.createTeam(name, address, areaName, shortName, tla);
    }


    public Team addPlayerToTeam(Long playerId, Long teamId) {
        return teamService.addPlayerToTeam(playerId, teamId);
    }

    public Team addCoachToTeam(Long coachId, Long teamId) {
        return teamService.addCoachToTeam(coachId, teamId);
    }
}
```

So im trying to debug putting a breakpoint on createTeam method but the request on postman is not reaching the backend. What im missing?

This is the repository in case you want to reproduce:
https://github.com/Romulo-S/TeamLeagueApp/tree/master

Comment: I am not sure if having a resolver is enough. What I have is a `@Controller` class with `@QueryMapping` and `@MutationMapping` methods, and their arguments annotated as `@Argument`. The last 3 annotations from the package `org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation`. And the Maven dependency is `org.springframework.boot / spring-boot-starter-graphql`, Spring Boot version 3.1.4.

Comment: Have tried this and the application doest not recognize the annotatiion

Comment: All dependencies you need is `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-graphql</artifactId>
  </dependency>`, you have a lot of trash dependencies in your projects, looks like mixing some old and new libraries. Especially the `com.graphql-java` looks weird, I do not need it in my code.

Comment: And I tried to git-clone your code and I am successfully able to import all the annotations, `import org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.Argument;` etc. So I don't understand your statement " the application doest not recognize the annotatiion"

Comment: '@MutationMapping' not applicable to type

Comment: i will, try to make some cleanup, but im doing diferent from you. Im separating mutations and querys in diferent classes. The tutorial says to use Component instead of Controller. II will try again and reach you back.

Comment: As I wrote before: `@Controller` goes to the **class**, `@QueryMapping` and `@MutationMapping` goes to **methods**, `@Argument` goes to method **arguments/parameters**. "`@MutationMapping` not applicable to type" error message means that you are trying to annotate a class with the annotation. I am telling you what works for me.

Comment: Thanks it worked! But for some reason the team is not being saved on the table. I pushed my changes.

Comment: Good to hear that it works. I will write it as a regular answer, you may accept it then.

Comment: If the team is not saved in the database table and you verified that the method is called, there might be a different problem in your code :) Test this part of your code **separately** and create an MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make GraphQL working in Spring Boot, you need the only Maven dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-graphql</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and then you need a controller class corresponding with your Graph QL schema:

```java
import org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.Argument;
import org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.MutationMapping;
import org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.QueryMapping;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
public class LinkGraphQLController {
    @QueryMapping
    public Team getTeamById(@Argument Long id) {
        ...
    }

    @MutationMapping
    public Team addPlayerToTeam(@Argument Long playerId, @Argument Long teamID) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The identifiers must match exactly your schema.

I have personally no experience with `Long` as Graph QL `ID` type, I always use `java.util.UUID`.

For the mandatory parameters (marked with `!` in the schema), just add `@org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated` on the class and `@jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull` on the parameters. If the parameter is not simple, add also `@Valid`.

Comment: ok so it is not necessary to implement GraphQLResolver?

Comment: How abou the field resolver? What annotation shoud i use in this classes instead of implement GraphQLResolver?

Comment: UUID is not working:  Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=com.br.leagueimport.entity.Coach]